# Is there a way to get better text on canvas?

Tags: canvas, text

Am I missing a trick - is there a way to get better looking text on a canvas tag? Eg:

http://www.rgraph.net/demos/bar-basic.html

The text antialiasing is not great IMO. I'm thinking (again - I go back and forth) of using DOM text positioned above the canvas - but this isn't great for all situations (eg taking a PNG of the canvas with toDataURL() would result in no text but it would suit a lot of situations)

Comment: Yes, canvas text is not as good as SVG or text in a native DOM element. No real workaround if you need a .png.

Comment: There is a theoretical solution, render the canvas text on an offscreen buffer (canvas) at double, or higher resolution and then downsample the buffer to the correct resolution. I could not find a perfect downsampler for text, the ones used by browsers and OS are very sophisticated and take into consideration the positioning of the RGB element within the display pixel (that is why zooming the bitmapped text has red and blue edges) . Though the square root of the mean of the summed squares (pixels in sample) does give a small improvement.

Comment: Thats a good idea! In the past I've done something similar - double the size of the canvas and everything on it and use CSS to size it to the desired dimensions so that everything gets scaled down. It gave good results but was too impractical to use. This sounds like a better way to go. After drawing the double size text on another canvas and using context.scale() to scale it down, how would you then find the dimensions of the text? I suppose you could use the getImageData function (http://www.rgraph.net/reference/getimagedata.html) and check the color of each pixel. That seems a  ballache.

Comment: Another way might be to measure the double size text and then have the resulting dimesions

Comment: As a bit of aside - here's an example of the issue that I made during me working on this: http://www.rgraph.net/fiddle/view.html/an-example-of-canvas-text The bottom one is DOM text positioned over the canvas.

Comment: Out of interest - are any of the browser manufacturers working on better text for canvas?

Comment: *...Out of interest...* There is a `Chrome.tabs` [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) that allows you to do a screen capture right inside Chrome. Warning: some configuration is required by the client. That would let you capture both your canvas plus any overlaying DOM text.

Comment: A complicated and probably unworkable solution: You can host a "headless browser" like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) on a server that would accept your chart image plus Html text elements and would return a screenshot image of the image+elements combined.

Comment: *Slow progress* I suspect that SVG drawn onto canvas will eventually support `.toDataURL` -- maybe in a sandboxed way. I suspect that the drawing engines of SVG and Canvas might be merged (their commands and renderings are remarkably similar) which will allow nicer SVG text.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I think I should use SVG... :-/ Its just not a nice API IMO.